# Custom Ribbon in Excel 2016 using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created an additional Menu and sub menu under it (i.e. customized the Excel ribbon). I also delete the custom menu when workbook closes. All works fine.

```
Private Const My_TAG = "MYXla"    
Private Const MY_TOOLS_MENU_ID As Long = 30007&    

Dim ToolsMenu As Office.CommandBarControl    
Dim ToolsMenuItem As Office.CommandBarControl    
Dim ToolsMenuControl As Office.CommandBarControl    

    Set ToolsMenu = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=MY_TOOLS_MENU_ID)  
    If ToolsMenu Is Nothing Then  
        MsgBox "Unable to access Tools menu.", vbOKOnly  
        Exit Sub  
    End If  

    Set ToolsMenuItem = ToolsMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, temporary:=True)  
    If ToolsMenuItem Is Nothing Then  
        MsgBox "Unable to add item to the Tools menu.", vbOKOnly  
        Exit Sub  
    End If  

    With ToolsMenuItem  
        .Caption = "&My Custom function name"  
        .BeginGroup = True  
        .Tag = My_TAG  
    End With  

    Set ToolsMenuControl = ToolsMenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)  
    If ToolsMenuControl Is Nothing Then  
        MsgBox "Unable to add item to Tools menu item.", vbOKOnly  
        Exit Sub  
    End If  

Private Sub Workbook_Close()   
   DeleteControls  
End Sub  

Private Sub DeleteControls()  

   Dim Ctrl As Office.CommandBarControl  

   On Error Resume Next  
    Set Ctrl = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:=My_TAG)  

    Do Until Ctrl Is Nothing  
        Ctrl.Delete  
        Set Ctrl = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:=My_TAG)  
    Loop  

End Sub
```

However when I open another .xlsm file, I see the same custom menu is still visible in the ribbon. I am surprised from where the values are coming.

Please suggest as I am sure it must be something small.

Thanks

Comment: Office Ribbon Customizations are better handled with the Ribbon X Editor https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor
Here some reference: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

Comment: Do you mean you open another `xlsm` file before or after you delete the controls? Bacause if you edit the ribbon like that it is applied to the `Application` which means it is visible in all Excel-Files you open until you delete the controls.

Comment: @Peh, I close the file which has the customization for the ribbon. After that I open normal .xls file then menu is not visible. However if I open a copy of that file from where I have deleted almost everthing ,  I mean literally everything and the extension is .xlsm, it still bring up the custom menu. I am baffled.

Comment: does it also happen if you create a brand new `xlsm` file?

Comment: @PeH, when I say copy of the file, I meant copy of the file which had custom code for ribbon and menu. But like I said, I have deleted everything from this file, but still menu comes up. Actually I received the code from somewhere and now I need to change the entries in custom menu, but unable to do so. Hence trying to remove everything to understand where the custom entries are coming from.

Comment: @PeH, it does not happen if I create a new xlsm file.

Comment: @Alok Then you didn't delete the VBA code properly or your file is corrupt. If I add your code to a file save it. Copy it. Delete the code, and save it. And open it it doesn't happen. So I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: @PeH Is there a way to share the file with you

Comment: @Alok Sorry no one here wants neither a corrupt file nor a file with VBA code from a unknown source that is known to cause weird stuff. Re-Check your VBA codes, or create a new file and copy over the data to the new file to solve it. Or save it as `xlsx` to remove all the VBA code, and then re-save it as `xlsm` and insert only the macros you need. Any of these solutions should fix it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I expect what is happening is that the toolbar customizations aren't being removed - that the VBA in the question hasn't completely removed them. Just deleting that VBA won't remove toolbar customizations that may be saved in the workbook, will it? (If this were Word, the problem would have entirely different dimensions, which was one very positive side of getting Ribbon XML in place of CommandBars...)

Comment: @Cindy Meister, are you saying that even if one deletes the entire VBA, the .xlsm file still has some location within it to save the toolbard customizations, which results in menu showing up when we open that file.

Comment: @Alok no, that's not the case. Again I assume your file is corrupt. You can test it doing the following: ① Open a new Excel file. Add a module and insert your code (the first part). Run it so the menu gets added. ② Save that file with the menu visible. Close it without deleting the menu. ③ Re-open that file: And the menu is gone. That means the menu only persists until you close Excel completely or until you remove the menu (using the last procedure of your code). • The menu is NOT saved in the file.